# Couldn't require openssl in ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems

I have openssl installed in my virtual machine ubuntu12.04lts.

When I run the gem command it gives error.

> Error: while executing gem (Gem::Exception)
>         Unable to require openssl. install openSSL and rebuilt ruby (preferred) or use non HTTPs sources

And I also test require openssl in irb mode.
it gives error.

> Loaderror: cannot load such file --openssl
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 `require'

I have openssl

```
$openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 mar 2012
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using and how did you install it?  You probably have to rebuild Ruby as it says in the error message.

Comment: Hi David I am using ruby2.1.0p0 of ruby. I installed it by built its source.

Comment: The problem looks like the filename: `--openssl` vs just `openssl` (unless Ruby prepends the dashes on error output). Is `openssl` accidentally getting formatted as a switch?

Comment: Hello noloader, I am sorry I could not understand what you just asking.  Is openssl accidentally getting formatted as a switch? what it mean how can I answer to this question. Help me to do Thanks :)

Comment: What if I do not want to run with openssl?

Comment: Without openssl enabled in ruby environment we are using.                      could not access remote gems. It shows clearly that **install openSSL and rebuilt ruby (preferred) or use non HTTPs sources.**  To use HTTPs sources ruby have to access to openssl library.

Answer (score 24):

Note: Calls to rubygems.org are deprecated - proceed with caution!

I had the same issue on Mac OSX after also building ruby2.1.0p0 from the source. I already had openssl installed. It appears that the reference in gems needed refreshing. I ran:

`gem source -r https://rubygems.org/` to remove

followed by

`gem source -a https://rubygems.org/` to read

After this, I was able to run `gems install bundler` successfully.

If you run into further errors, you can try `./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl` in your ruby downloaded dir/.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will put a note that this solution is deprecated, as the answer is old now.

Comment: thanks. I just had this same problem after installing ruby 2.2 on linux from sources also. Your fix worked

Comment: More than being deprecated, this is scary from a security standpoint.

Comment: @DrewStephens I'm not very knowledgable about security - would you mind elaborating? Would be good to know!

Comment: @jspacek Not using HTTP**S** opens the connection up to man-in-the-middle attacks.  HTTPS without certificate pinning is still susceptible to a lot of attacks, but at least they require trusted certificates.  Less important in the case of retrieving gems is that **S** prevents attackers from eavesdropping on your HTTP requests.

Comment: It seems that running "gem source -a https://rubygems.org/" works just as well as http. Actually, http version now prints out the warning "https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org/" for the unsecure version. I'll edit the original. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: i can't run `gem source`, it says `cannot load such file -- openssl`

Answer (score 18):

I got this error while using debian where openssl was in /usr/bin.

Following the suggestion of jspacek I reconfigured ruby using:

```
./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin
```

After make and sudo make install I was able to install rails.

Comment: This is the issue with my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian / Debian

Comment: This really help！

Comment: For Homebrew users: `brew install openssl; rvm reinstall 2.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl``

Answer (score 16):

make sure you have libssl-dev installed:

```
dpkg -s libssl-dev
```

if not, install it:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 8):

In case someone else has this problem, try reinstalling your Ruby version with openssl included

```
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.4.0 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

You might already have openssl - so you can ignore the first step.
This helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm leaving this answer for reference to future Googlers:

Type all these commands in your Terminal (OSX) just to be extra sure you've done everything (this is what eventually worked for me)

```
rvm get stable
brew update
brew doctor
brew install openssl
rvm install ruby-2.1 (or whatever version)
rvm use (ruby version here)  i.e. rvm use ruby-2.1
rvm gemset create NAME   i.e. rvm gemset create rails41
gem install rails -v 4.1
```

Finally...

As many commenters have pointed out - you need OpenSSL installed before you compile ruby before you install rails (or other gems)

Answer (score 3):

You probably built Ruby from source before installing OpenSSL.  Make sure you install it and then try reconfiguring and rebuilding Ruby.

Comment: doing `$ openssl` in bash works for me...but trying to run any `gem` command ends up in `cannot load such file -- openssl`

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was struggling with ruby installations due to the recent auto-update in openssl version from 1.0 to 1.1 and wanted to revert it back to older version. No other solution except the one given below worked for me:

`brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p551 --with-openssl-dir='/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0'
gem update --system`

Now my ruby runs with openssl 1.0 whereas all other libraries are running on the default openssl version 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding Ruby after running `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libreadline-dev libgdbm-dev` can solve this issue.

I found this solution [here](http://www.larshaendler.com/2015/05/20/unable-to-require-openssl-install-openssl-and-rebuild-ruby-on-ubuntu-14-lts/).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error installing Ruby with RVM. Nothing worked. I switched to [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue and tried to solve it by following guides. The "rebuild ruby" is an important step!

after openssl_devel is installed

```
cd folder_of_ruby_source_code/ext/openssl  
ruby ./extconf.rb  
make  
make install  

cd folder_of_ruby_source_code  
./configure  
make clean       <= clean is important here
make  
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a case of missing dependencies.

i *thought* i had all the dependencies required to install ruby, but i too was getting an openSSL and readline error.

i attempted to install ruby with RVM without root privileges which failed but gave me a list of missing dependencies. i then installed the dependencies with a package manager. i then re-attempted to install ruby from source from the beginning, and everything worked OK

the dependencies that were missing, for me, were:

```
 patch libyaml-devel autoconf gcc-c++
 readline-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel
 automake libtool bison sqlite-devel
```

but they may be different for you.

**update:** i don't originally remember where exactly i found this list, but a quick search found similar lists on the following pages, which might also help you:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-6-with-rvm

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-ubuntu-fedora-from-source.html

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me:

1. Fixed ruby install:

   brew upgrade openssl; 
   openssldir=`which openssl`
   rvm reinstall ruby-2.4.2 --with-openssl-dir=$openssldir
2. Removed and re-added sources for gems

   gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
   gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/

Answer (score -3):

Do you use RVM?

If not, try using it and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I already installed ruby from its source.So as you said to install rvm. How to do it. Whether i want to remove ruby i already installed and install ruby with help of rvm. I have no clear idea if you can tell me. what difference between install ruby from   source and install by rvm. please let me know i need some good reference. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using rvm and searching for documentation on SSL installation support. I'm going to follow @notaceo 's advice