# Error for macos sierra install cocoapods

Tags: macos, rubygems

When i install **mac os sierra**, trying install **cocoapods**, but appear error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
>       Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources

but i already installed **openssl** and **ruby**,i really don't know is why,does anyone know?

[image: this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't require openssl in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201493/couldnt-require-openssl-in-ruby)

Comment: but how can solve?

Answer (score 1):

Install Cocoapods by below 3 commands

```
sudo gem update --system -n/usr/local/bin
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
pod setup
```